# Using same sqlalchemy models with different mysql_engine types, InnoDB and MEMORY

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use same SQLAlchemy  model definition for both production and testing. I'm going to use MySQL in both cases as I heavily rely on specific MySQL features like LAG function (so sqlite is not an option). But in the same time I want to run tests faster, so need to place test tables in memory.

Initially I thought that I may write test tables creation code by iterating over all `Base.metadata.sorted_tables` and setting them `mysql_engine = 'MEMORY'` attribute, or assigning `__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'MEMORY'}` for all ORM class instances before tables creation.

But that seems be not working, tables are created using InnoDB. The only way to make in-memory tables is to specify `__table_args__ = {'mysql_engine': 'MEMORY'}` explicitly in class definition, which is inappropriate for production, obviously. I've looked over SQLAlchemy documentation and didn't found much about assigning that kind of values dynamically, so is it ever possible? Or I need to customize classes declaration by imposing some kind of global tables storage setting?

Comment: The test environment should mimic the prod as clisely as posdible. Using a different mysql storage engine will cause you problems in production as these behave very differently.